# Use image to open record in another form

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, catalog

I am really struggling and wondered if someone could help please?  I am trying to set up a database with images which I have done and used the file path of my pictures.  It works well and that is great, but the next step is to have a form that just displays the pictures from each record to act as a catalogue and then When you click on a particular picture in that form it opens up another form that contains all the records and goes directly to that specified record. We have managed to get it to work for the first picture and record but can't work out how to make it go to the next record for the next image.  I am trying to use a multi line form for this and only have the picture visible.  I am just using a basic code as I have only just started with VBA but I believe this may not work.  Can someone please help advise me?

I have used the following code which was suggested online for working with pictures and then there are a couple of other vba code to add to it.  I need to create a catalogue inventory but we want to click on the picture of the inventory item which then opens a form with all the detail.  I have found a work around with using the continous form and transparent buttons which take you to the specific record but you can't seem to change the layout.  Ideally I am looking to have a form with just the images in a grid style going across the page and not just a list going down the page...if that makes sense?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function DisplayImage(ctlImageControl As Control, strImagePath As Variant) As String
On Error GoTo Err_DisplayImage

Dim strResult As String
Dim strDatabasePath As String
Dim intSlashLocation As Integer

With ctlImageControl
 If IsNull(strImagePath) Then
     .Visible = False
     strResult = "No image name specified."
 Else
     If InStr(1, strImagePath, "\") = 0 Then
         ' Path is relative
         strDatabasePath = CurrentProject.FullName
         intSlashLocation = InStrRev(strDatabasePath, "\", Len(strDatabasePath))
         strDatabasePath = Left(strDatabasePath, intSlashLocation)
         strImagePath = strDatabasePath & strImagePath
     End If
     .Visible = True
     .Picture = strImagePath
     strResult = "Image found and displayed."
 End If
End With

Exit_DisplayImage:
 DisplayImage = strResult
 Exit Function

Err_DisplayImage:
 Select Case Err.Number
     Case 2220       ' Can't find the picture.
         ctlImageControl.Visible = False
         strResult = "Can't find image in the specified name."
         Resume Exit_DisplayImage:
     Case Else       ' Some other error.
         MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
         strResult = "An error occurred displaying image."
         Resume Exit_DisplayImage:
 End Select
End Function
```

Comment: If you managed to get it work for one image (the first one), what difference would be to do the same for the following ones? Why don't you post the code you use? It will be much easier to suggest how to adapt it instead of writing code from scratch... How many such images does your code handles? Do you want to display all of them on the form? If yes, did you solve this aspect?

Comment: i have added the code above which is one that was displayed as a sample to try out with northwinds.  I am really new to VBA and I don't completely understand the elements. I also think I am trying to create something that access can't seem to do?

Comment: I think to recall, that the trick with the transparent button is the only reliable. However, _you can't seem to change the layout_ makes little sense; you can change the layout as much as you wish.

Comment: as a new person to this area and forgive me but I have tried every way I can think of to get my pictures to go across the screen opposed to just going vertical.  The multi item form/continuous form brings in each item but I don't know how to get items to go across as it seems it just brings the same record in when you go across as it comes under item 1 etc. How can you edit  so that you can get items 1 , 2 , 3 and 4 to go horizontally across the screen opposed to vertically?

Comment: You need to show code that uses `DisplayImage` (should be `Detailssection_Paint` event). Any reason not to bind form to a query containing path to image and set Image-Control to that field? You may have a continuous form with several Image-Controls next to each other, then create a query that fetches as many image paths in one row as you have controls to fill.